# Is GNU assembler bundled with GCC provided by Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source, gcc

I'm on Intel Mac running the latest Monterey. Already have [GCC 13](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gcc) installed using Homebrew.

I'm trying to build [sectorlisp](https://github.com/jart/sectorlisp).
Unfortunately still fails, because **as** (the LLVM assembler) rejected it. Perhaps there are some incompatibilities. So I setup a Debian VM, installed GCC etc, and succesfully built it. Hmm.

I couldn't fine **as** executable in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin`. Perhaps there's an easy way to install GNU assembler on macOS?

Comment: There are beta versions that are pre-release. When you say latest, do you mean you're running a beta? If you can list the build / version then the question will remain relevant even when "latest" doesn't mean the same thing on the same day as time progresses. An edit to explain with a code snippet what "as (the LLVM assembler) rejected it." looks like - we also might be of more help.